# Change $TERMINFO in bashrc script

Tags: bash, terminal, readline

I'm trying to set `TERMINFO="$HOME/.terminfo"` within my `.bashrc` script. The reason being is that my terminal isn't in the system `terminfo` location, and so I have its `terminfo` file in my home directory.
The problem here is that the change doesn't take effect for the current shell, only subshells. I'm guessing it's because readline is being initialized before bash reads the `.bashrc` file.

So is there any way to solve this issue? Perhaps some way to re-initialize readline so the changed `$TERMINFO` takes effect?
I'm trying to avoid doing an `exec bash` after setting it, as then I have to make sure I don't end up in a re-exec loop, and that's just ugly (though doing `exec bash` after setting it does work).

EDIT: This is **not** a issue running the script. I know for a fact the `.bashrc` script is being run and that `$TERMINFO` is being set. Running `echo $TERMINFO` after the shell has finished starting shows the correct value.

EDIT2: It appears this might be bash or readline library version related. I can't duplicate the issue with bash-4.2.20 and readline-6.2_p1, but I can with bash-3.2 and readline-5.1.3.

"No" is an acceptable answer if it's not possible. But it would be nice to know what's going on that causes the answer to be "no".

Comment: can you post an answer as to what the newest version you've found this affects, then we'll close

Comment: @xenoterracide No, this question should not be closed! Even if it doesn't apply to the latest version of all involved software, it's still useful for people running older versions. There's no reason to block answers or delete the question.

Comment: @gilles going on the suggestion of another mod, but I'm really kind of indifferent.

Comment: From what I see in the bash source, the terminal handling code is reinitialized (`sv_terminal` in `variables.c`) when `TERMINFO` changes at least since 2.05. I haven't looked at readline or tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after digging around some more, I found what's going on. RHEL5's build of bash doesn't use terminfo at all (why, who knows, it's Red Hat), it uses termcap. However, there is apparently another bash on the box which does use terminfo. This is why subshells and re-execing would work, as they would use the other bash, not the default one. I feel stupid for not noticing this.

This can be determined from comparing 2 commands:

```
# ldd "$BASH"
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4f1fd000)
    libtermcap.so.2 => /lib64/libtermcap.so.2 (0x0000003e0bc00000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003e07000000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003e06c00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003e06800000)

# ldd `which bash`
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff643fd000)
    libncurses.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.5 (0x0000003e0d800000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003e07000000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003e06c00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003e06800000)
```

Noticing that one is linked against libtermcap, and the other against libncurses.

I should have specified that I was using RHEL here, as that's apparently the critical factor. Why they use termcap when pretty much everyone else in the world has abandoned it makes no sense, but there it is.

Comment: Does the rpm changelog or spec file give any clues why they chose term cap?

Comment: According to the [bash configure file](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/configure) termcap is the default.  And the [Fedora spec file](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/gitweb/?p=bash.git;a=blob;f=bash.spec;h=894dc898acf11d6d0a5d74932f14f28ba8468bf8;hb=HEAD) shows they don't pass `--with-curses`.

Answer (score 0):

From `man bash` - the invocation section:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands  from  the  first  one that exists and is readable.

To set up your environment, include the `terminfo` line (and any other environmental variables you would like to set) in either `.bash_profile` or `.profile`.

See this [Superuser answer for more detail](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile).

Comment: Already tried that, doesnt work. In fact my `.bash_profile` sources my `.bashrc`. I'm dead certain its being set because `echo $TERMINFO` shows it.

Answer (score 0):

bash only reads `.bashrc` when it starts.

So you need to do `source ~/.bashrc` to re-load it in the current session.