# bash not reading $TERMINFO on login (over SSH)

Tags: bash, terminal, readline

I have a OpenVZ Fedora 20 VPS that when I SSH into, my termcap file stored in `$XDG_DATA_HOME/terminfo/x/xterm-termite`, isn't being read, despite having `TERMINFO=$XDG_DATA_HOME/terminfo` set. If I execute a subshell bash it works fine. Or if I add `exec bash` to the end of my `.profile` it works fine.

I saw [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36186/change-terminfo-in-bashrc-script) and suspected it could be the same thing. But I'm logging in with the `/usr/bin` version bash already anyway

```
$ echo $BASH
/usr/bin/bash
$ which bash
/usr/bin/bash
```

I also tried Ubuntu 13.10 on the VPS and saw the same problem.

Patrick's question did get me thinking though, I know the underlying OS of the VPS is REHL. Could that somehow be affecting it?

---

I source a file called [`environment`](https://github.com/EvanPurkhiser/dots-personal/blob/master/base/bash/environment#L23) in my `.profile`, which sets the `$TERMINFO` environment variable if the `terminfo` directory exists in `XDG_DATA_HOME`.

```
$ echo $TERMINFO
/home/evan/.local/share/terminfo
$ echo $XDG_DATA_HOME
/home/evan/.local/share
$ find $TERMINFO
/home/evan/.local/share/terminfo
/home/evan/.local/share/terminfo/x
/home/evan/.local/share/terminfo/x/xterm-termite
$ echo $TERM
xterm-termite
```

This works fine on my Linode VPS.

Comment: Where is this being set? In what file? How are they being set? Show us the exact line. What do `echo $TERMINFO` and `echo $XDG_DATA_HOME` return?

Comment: I updated the question with that output and then some :)

Answer (score 2):

Bash loads the terminfo database entry only when it starts (like most programs) or when you change the `TERM` variable. Changing the `TERMINFO` variable has no immediate effect: it is only used when the terminfo entry is loaded, it doesn't trigger a reload.

When you run `exec bash`, this starts a new instance of bash which loads the terminal entry based on the current values of `TERM` and `TERMINFO`.

You can reload the terminfo database by assigning to `TERM`. Bash optimizes `TERM=$TERM`, it doesn't reload the data, so you'll need to go via an intermediate value.

```
TERMINFO=…
# Reload the terminfo entry to take the new value of $TERMINFO into account
old_TERM=$TERM; TERM=dumb; TERM=$old_TERM; unset old_TERM
```

Comment: You're right, that does indeed work. (even shorter: `TERM=${TERM}X; TERM=${TERM:0:-1}`). Can you explain why I don't see this behaviour (of not reading the TERMINFO on start) in some of my other machines where I have it setup the same way, particular on a Arch Linux box (Bash 4.3.11), and a Ubuntu Linode VPS (Bash 2.2.37)? (The box where it isn't working is Bash 4.2.47)

Comment: Also, just doing `TERM=$TERM` does seem to work :)

Comment: Spoke too soon :( this works when entering this from the prompt after just logging in. But adding this at the end of my `.profile` does _not_ work.

Comment: @EvanPurkhiser Did you try with the code I provided (and not just `TERM=$TERM`? I can't see why it wouldn't work from `.profile`. Make sure you have `strace` installed and add `sh -c "strace -p $$ -e file -o ~/bash.login.strace & :"` to `.profile` before the lines that manipulate `TERM` or `TERMINFO`. The file `bash.login.strace` will contain a trace of the files that the login shell accesses after that point, post that trace.

Comment: I did use the code you provided. [Here's a snippet of my .profile](https://gist.github.com/EvanPurkhiser/7614cef267324ba325e4) and [here's the strace](https://gist.github.com/EvanPurkhiser/b0037022f1d03dab65c4). Also, [here is a strace of one of my servers](https://gist.github.com/EvanPurkhiser/021cb87f5c0f3546cfc7) that works fine without having to do any special TERM hackery.